(kdb+/q) How to return a single combined output when looping through two list parameters (one on inner loop/one on outer loop)
I am performing a string search on 929 strings in a list.
I am looping through 7 different strings.
The issue I am having is how to return the output as one and not returning it 7 times for each different string that is searched.
q){{ss[x;y]}[;x]each exec rd from rdeFunc}each exec v from dToCol
..
q)

q)count {{ss[x;y]}[;x]each exec rd from rdeFunc}each exec v from dToCol
7
q)

q)count each {{ss[x;y]}[;x]each exec rd from rdeFunc}each exec v from dToCol
929 929 929 929 929 929 929
q)


Can you give a sample with some data? and explore more the shape and type of data you wish to get as a result? It's unclear what you expect as output.

@rianoc it is just a standard ss so will return the first index where the strings from exec v from dToCol are found in the strings of exec rd from rdeFunc or if not found then will return a null value for that row

return the output as one how do you wish to aggregate the data down from 7 to 1? count ? raze ? any ? Is the result a single list of booleans? A nested list of longs?

@rianoc I want to ensure I have all the rows with indexes i.e. where a match has been found and then in the remaining rows where no match was found across the 7 loops just return the null. So i guess I almost want to join the 7 outputs into one where an index (number) overwrites a null and the remaining nulls stay the same.  lj is what I think of

Sample data:
dToCol:([] v:("aa";"cc";"ff"))
rdeFunc:([] rd:("aa";"bb";"cc";"dd";"ee";"ff"))

Your code gives 3 lists of 6:
q)count each {{ss[x;y]}[;x]each exec rd from rdeFunc}each exec v from dToCol
6 6 6

If you wanted 6 lists of 3 you can use flip:
count each flip {{ss[x;y]}[;x]each exec rd from rdeFunc}each exec v from dToCol
3 3 3 3 3 3

Or reorder your query to not need the flip:
count each {ss[x] each exec v from dToCol}each exec rd from rdeFunc
3 3 3 3 3 3

Or use \:/: each-left each-right to simplify further:
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#left-right-cross
count each ss\:/:[dToCol`v;rdeFunc`rd]
3 3 3 3 3 3

Verify all results are exact matches:
r3:ss\:/:[dToCol`v;rdeFunc`rd]
r2:{ss[x] each exec v from dToCol}each exec rd from rdeFunc
r1:flip {{ss[x;y]}[;x]each exec rd from rdeFunc}each exec v from dToCol
r1~r2
1b
r2~r3
1b


I would require the index itself to be returned and not just a boolean like response.
So once combined it would look like below
,0  ,0 ,0

i am going to use the indexes to then extract the string from each of the strings a match was found in

Have added {x where count each x} example to not return empties.

`q){{x where count each x}{ss[x;y]}[;x]each exec rd from rdeFunc}each exec v from dToCol
()
(,22;,22;,22;,22;,22)
(,17;,17;,17;,17;,17)
(,26;,26;,26;,26;,26;,26;,26;,26;,26;,20;,20;,20;,20;,20;,20;,20;,20;,20;,20;,20;,18;,18;,18;,18;,18;,18;,18;,18;,18;,18;,18;,18)
(,23;,23;,23;,23;,23;,23;,23;,23;,23;,23;,23;,23;,23;,35;,35;,35;,35;,35;,35;,35;,35)
(,37;,37;,37;,37;,37;,37;,37;,37;,37;,37;,37;,37;,37;,37;,29;,29;,29;,29;,29;,29;,29;,29;,29;,29;,29;,29;,29;,38;,38;,38;,38;,38;,38;,38;,40;,40;,40;,40;,40;,40;,40)
(,48;,48;,48;,48)`

It doesn't seem to return the null values or the row at which each index is found. If it where to include the null values for each return above (so there would be 929 elements returned for each) then i would be able to see the position of each row containing the match. Atm I just have the indexes but no idea what row they correspond to

Yes that is why I am unsure still of why you  are unhappy with the initial output. It has all the information you need. These attempts to aggregate or change the shape will throw away information. Unless all you are looking for is to flip the original output?

Ahh I see the simple flip gets it into the desired output that I can work with. thanks a lot for your time and help

I've improved the answer now it's clear what was wanted. If you can include a small sample input and desired output in future it makes answering questions a lot easier.
